# Move site page from one module/feature to another and redeploy?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a site page that was being deployed within a module that was initially part of one project, and I deployed via wsp to my development server and everything was good. During development I refactored it and moved the page to a different module within a separate project, updated the page and redeployed the wsp to the development server.  Unfortunately for some reason the updated page is not being deployed on development, but instead ignored.  I think this is due to the original page being deployed as part of a different feature/module at first and then the same page being moved to a different feature/module.  When I deploy to production the new version of the page gets deployed each time, I believe this is due to the fact that the page was only ever deployed in one feature/module on production.  Has anyone seen this where SP does not deploy a page when it gets moved from one feature/module to another?

Here is my module xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="SitePages" Url="SitePages">
        <File Path="SitePages\PASSHome.aspx" Url="PASSHome.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" />
        <File Path="SitePages\WorkflowStats.aspx" Url="WorkflowStats.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" />
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Are the files being deployed to the same url (ie same library) from module to module?

Comment: They are being deployed in the same Site Pages library.

Answer (score 0):

First up rename the page activate the feature and see if it gets deployed. If it doesn't check below!

When you moved the page to another solution how did you do this?
Create new module
Move the page in File explorer to the new module.
Right click (in VS) on the module
Add Existing item
Select the page

If so click on the page in your solution and check that the properties of the page: Specifically check that the page has a deployment type of ElementFile

Many Thanks

Truez

Comment: Both pages are set to Deployment Type of ElementFile.